# Error when using the plugin with the new Aurelia CLI

Tags: aurelia

I'm creating a new project of *Aurelia* with the *CLI* tool (`au new`) with typescript template and need to use *aurelia-dragula*.

I installed aurelia-dragula with *npm* and start using it in my typescript files.

When I run `"au run --watch"` , I get an error:

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\temp\client\src\dragula.js']"

If I open my ts file , I have a problem with the import statement

`"import {dragula} from 'dragula';"`

> Module ''dragula'' has no exported member dragula

Any idea please ? Did you use this plugin with the new Aurelia CLI project ?

Comment: Did you do the steps here - https://github.com/aurelia/cli#adding-client-libraries-to-your-project ?

Answer (score 2):

First, add `aurelia-dragula` as a dependency in your `aurelia.json` file.

```
// aurelia_project/aurelia.json

"dependencies" : {

    "aurelia-task-queue",
    "aurelia-templating",
    "aurelia-templating-binding",
    {
      "name": "aurelia-dragula",
      "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dragula/dist/amd",
      "main": "dragula"
    }

}
```

Second, to prevent the TypeScript compiler from complaining, add the following [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) to your `custom_typings` directory.

```
// custom_typings/aurelia-dragula.d.ts

declare module "aurelia-dragula";
```

Third, import it using this syntax.

```
// src/app.ts

import * as Dragula from 'aurelia-dragula';
```